# Grep last match from file

Tags: linux, redhat, grep, awk

I'm running the following command against a log file and only wanting to get the last/latest match.  Sometimes there may only be one match, other times there may be multiple, which is causing an issue for me since the following command is returning both matches:

```
cat "$(ls -t | head -n1)" | grep -P "(NODE1[\s\S]*TEST\s=\sPOWER[\s\S]*OUTPUT\s=\s\d+?.*\s+;?)"

>>>>> (results in)...

NODE1 2018-03-06 12:01:23
  TEST = POWER
  EVENT_TIME = 2018-03-06 12:01:23
  OUTPUT = 12

;

NODE1 2018-03-06 12:03:23
  TEST = POWER
  EVENT_TIME = 2018-03-06 12:03:23
  OUTPUT = 7

;
```

I need the last matching group in the event there are multiple.  Is this possible with grep/regex or do I need to pipe the results into sed/awk?  If so, how?

Comment: Hard way is pipe your commant to tail -n <number_of_lines_of_your_group>.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk problem is I don't know how many lines I need to capture.

Comment: You can use 'tac' instead of 'cat' and rewrite grep pattern for backward.

Comment: If it's possible, put little sample of file in [patebin.com](http://www.pastebin.com). I will try to write pattern.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk https://pastebin.com/n2iDY8uY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to you this solution:

```
cat <your_source_file> | sed -n '/NODE1/,/;/p' | tr '\n' '|' | awk -F ';' '{print $(NF-1)}'|tr '|' '\n'
```

`sed -n '/NODE1/,/;/p'` - find 'NODE1' blocks.

`tr '\n' '|'` convert newlines to record separator, so table columns will be separated by ';'.

`awk -F ';' '{print $(NF-1)}'` - print last-1 table column.

`tr '|' '\n'` - backward to previous view for record.

`awk -F ';' '{for(i=(NF-1); i>0; i--){ if($i ~ "TEST = POWER"){print $i} } }'` - only "TEST = POWER" events.

Comment: You're the man!  This is way more consistent than the results I was getting to `tac | .. | tac`

Comment: One question... how can I amend this to only get the last 'TEST = POWER` command run?

Comment: Just a minute, I'm trying :) I have an idea.

Comment: I've supplemented answer with your wishes ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Yurij's suggestion, I started looking into using `tac` instead of cat, and reversing my `grep` statement.  Now, I'm looking at the file from the bottom up and grabbing the first match:

`tac "$(ls -t | head -n1)" | grep -m 1 -P "\d+[\s\S]*TEST\s=\sTXPOWER" | tac`

Answer (score 0):

I find `perl` more convenient for this:

```
perl -lane 'if(/^NODE1 /&&($#n=-1)../^;$/){push @n,$_} END{print $_ for @n}' file
```

**Explanation:**

• `perl` Practical Extraction and Reporting Language.
• `-lane` switches commonly helpful for one-liners.
• `'` start of the actual program instructions
• `if(/^NODE1 /&&($#n=-1)../^;$/)` consider only portions of text beginning with a line stat starts with `NODE1` followed by a whitespace, and ending with a line containing a single semicolon.
• `/^NODE1 /&&($#n=-1)` reset the `@n` array at the start of the text portion.
• `{push @n,$_}` save each line in the text portion as an element of an array called `@n`
• `END{print $_ for @n}` when the whole file has been parsed, print the text portion saved in `@n`.
• `'` end of the program instructions.
• `file` this is a placeholder for the name of the file you wish to process.